# how to take dump of a table in parts and save it on different server?

Tags: database, mysql, database-backups

I have a DB server and it has a table of 90 GB. Now I want to take a back up of that table.
But DB is almost full and I cannot take back up into the same server.

Is there any way of taking backup using `mysqldump -u username -ppassword dbname tablename > different_server_location`

I used to do it on same server these days.

example:

`mysqldump -u username -ppassword dbname tablename > /tmp/file_name`

Since there is NO space available on DB server, how can I take backup of a table which is 90 GB!

and can I take backup of a file in few pieces. I mean 10 GB at once and so on ?

Comment: If the path to which you write the dumpfile is on another partition/disk (e.g. a network mount), then you will not be limited by the space remaining on the partition in which MySQL's data files are stored.

Comment: @eggyal : Yes, I want to write the dumpfile on another location. I mean on different server. In short, I want to take back up of DB to staging server. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes... *if the path to which you write the dumpfile...*.  Ugh, I'm just repeating myself.  Alternatively, if MySQL is accessible from the remote host, you could run mysqldump from there.

Comment: more details:
`mysqldump -u username -ppassword dbname tablename > username@stagingserver_name:/tmp/sqlfile_name`. But this is not resulting

Comment: Suggest you `mount` that remote path somewhere in your filesystem first.  This question is moving off-topic for SO; perhaps ask on [su] if you're not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you dump from another server in same network like:

```
mysqldump --host=myserver -u backup mydb > test.sql
```